C# Grpc Client error: remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid
I had a Grpc client taking to a Grpc Windows service.. at least until yesterday.  All of a sudden the client just stopped sending messages to the service.  After some time I realized that IIS had an old certificate that expired 5/2/2024.  So I removed that, cleared cert cache, rebooted, and still getting the following error:
Exception thrown: 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
An exception of type 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.")

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer: Error: Connection ID "17654110540902957062", Request ID "80000007-0000-f500-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.")
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthenticationWithTelemetryAsync(Boolean isAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp2ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.HttpConnectionWaiter`1.WaitForConnectionAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken requestCancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.BalancerHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.<SendAsync>g__SendAsyncWithTelemetry|6_0(HttpMessageHandler handler, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.GetResponseHeadersCoreAsync()
   at CADEproto.CADEservice.CADEserviceClient.SendMessage(CADErequest request, Metadata headers, Nullable`1 deadline, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Data\CADE.Core.Dev\GrpcWebClient\obj\Debug\net7.0\CADEserviceGrpc.cs:line 109
   at Program.<>c.<<Main>$>b__0_0(HttpContext context) in D:\Data\CADE.Core.Dev\GrpcWebClient\Program.cs:line 79
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()

I went to Control Panel, Internet Options, Content tab and uploaded the cert to the personal and others.  I can see the new cert in both places.  I cleared cache, rebooted, still got the error.
I've got a workaround but it's not safe:
var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(address, new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });

This client is located on the server and calls the Windows Service also on the same server so I'm not overly worried about not checking certificates but I'd really like to fix this properly and would appreciate any ideas on how to do that.
